# Internal NLB gives connection refused

Tags: curl, amazon-eks, vpn, connection-refused, nlb

I have a web application deployed on EKS cluster, exposed via internal NLB on 8443/TCP port.

I tried:

```
 curl -kv https://NLB-DNS:8443
```

from the VPN and I got "connection refused" while, if I try curl from an eks pod, I get the correct answer.

I tried also:

```
kubectl port-forward svc/service-name 8443:8443 

curl -kv https://127.0.0.1:8443
```

and  I got correct answer

Any idea about this issue?

Thank You